# Image/Video sharing on iOS, preparing alert progress box, what component is this in Swift library?

Tags: ios, swift

I always see apps that provide this "Preparing" screen to show its progress whenever I share a big video. I know Swift has `UIAlertController` that can show a popup, but it's bare so it leads to think that this Preparing alert box gotta be an Apple built-in framework because many other apps have the exact same UI when sharing a large asset. Anyone know what this alert box is call?

[Preparing screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dimbE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default dialog box to display Progress HUD. But, you can customise the `UIAlertController`. Even others also will do the same.

```
    @IBAction func showPopover(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let alertTitle = "Preparing...\n\n\n\n\n"
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 250, height: 110)
        let customView = UIView(frame: rect)
        alertController.view.addSubview(customView)
        
        
        let progressLabel = ProgressLabel()
        let kLabelSize = 60.0
        progressLabel.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (customView.frame.width/2.0)-(kLabelSize/2.0), y: (customView.frame.height/2.0)-(kLabelSize/2.0)), size: CGSize(width: kLabelSize, height: kLabelSize))
        progressLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        progressLabel.textAlignment = .center
        progressLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        progressLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        progressLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3
        progressLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        customView.addSubview(progressLabel)


        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("cancel")})

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})
        updateProgress(progressLabel)
    }
    
    var progress = 1.0
    func updateProgress(_ label: ProgressLabel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
            label.text = "\(self.progress)%"
            self.progress += 1.0
            if self.progress <= 100.0 {
                self.updateProgress(label)
            }
        }
    }
 }

class ProgressLabel: UILabel {
    var value: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    // Create your own circle shape layer to render the progress
    private var progressLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

**Note:**
Here, you have to take consideration for `y` value of `customview` based on the `AlertController's` title and message text size.